# How can I save both the HTML5 canvas marks AND the image loaded in the canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas that I load an image into. The user then makes marks on the canvas with the loaded image as a background. When I attempt to save the image (using toDataURL()) AND the marks made by the user, it only saves the marks, but not the "background" image I loaded into the canvas. Can I save both in one shot?

I want to reload the image and the marks later. If I can't save both in one Base64 string, then I'd have to do some kind of overlay of images if that's even possible. It would be best to just save it.

Below is the code to load the image and save the marks. I didn't think making the marks code was relevant so I left details out.

Thanks for any help.

```html
function SetUp() {

/// load the image
LoadImage();

/// Draw existing marks
DrawMarkedItems();
}


        function LoadImage() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("imageView");
            if (canvas != null) {
                if (canvas.getContext) {
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function () {
                        context.drawImage(img, 15, 15, 620, 475);
                    }
                    img.src = '../Images/Outline.png';
                }
            }
        }



function DrawMarkedItems() {

var canvas = document.getElementById("imageView");
if (canvas != null) {
 if (canvas.getContext) {
  var list = GetInfoList();  
  if (list.length == 0)
   return;

  var pairs = list.split('|').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs; i++) {

  /// Get the X,Y cooridinates other data 
  /// saved previously in GetInfoList()
  /// and draw the marks back on the 
  /// canvas with image backgroun
  
  }
 }
}
}


        function SaveImage()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("imageView");
            var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.1);
            image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
                 
            /// WebMethod in code behind
            var retval = PageMethods.SaveImage(image);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I was loading the background image first, then drawing the existing marks on the canvas (In Setup() calling LoadImage() then DrawMarkedItems()).

I moved the call to DrawMarkedItems() into the LoadImage() function, specifically in the img.onload function.

Below is the modified function. Hope this helps someone else:

```
function LoadImage() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("imageView");
        if (canvas != null) {
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = '../Images/Outline.png';  //moved up for cosmetics
                img.onload = function () {
                    context.drawImage(img, 15, 15, 620, 475);
                    ***DrawMarkedItems();***
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```